# Should <button> contain nested DOM element or not?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I did not realize is it bad or not, according to the W3C rules about HTML semantic writing - how we should write the `button` element with descended elements?

In way, like this one:

```html
<button>
 <div>
   <span>'hi'</span>
 </div>
</button>
```

or only this:

```html
<button>'hi'</button>
```

Comment: @trincot the question is about accessability side of our modern web - on my opinion we should not use nested elements inside `button` tag. But it just my opinion, that why I placed question here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code in [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) & the error shown is

> Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

[image: W3C Validator result]

Answer (score 2):

Basically the specification does not allow that.

It might work for you but it's not the best practice.

As you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) button must be no interactive content descendant.

You also can verify your html in [here](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)

Comment: But if you do a div and handle it as a button you get in the same predicament, meaning, it is still not best practice. :)

Comment: There are many ways, also `<input type="button" />` for example.

Comment: Oh, yes! that's what I'm looking for! Thank you. Btw, there you have a downside in your answer in - "You could do a div and design it as a button and handle your submit as well.". We should not use `div` for any particular cases, where we have already specified tag element, in this case it `button.`

Answer (score 2):

Nested tags within a `<button>` is [not valid](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-button-element) and returns the following [when tested](https://validator.w3.org/):

> Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context.

Non-nested tags is the correct way to go.

See for your self if you like. I used the follow HTML to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<title>Button test HTML</title> 
</head>
<body>
<button>
<div>
   <span>'not valid'</span>
 </div>
</button>
<button>Valid</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`button` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#the-button-element) may contain elements that are [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) without also being [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#interactive-content-2). In other words: elements that get used on the intra-paragraph level (sometimes called *inline elements*), and that don’t allow user interaction.

For example, this means it may contain `span` elements, but not `div` elements. So this is valid:

```html
<button>
  <span>'hi'</span>
</button>
```